# mysql column auto update issue

Tags: mysql, auto-update

Here is my table columns

id----time_created----time_updated----db_user

when a row is added to this table, or any updated occurred, the db_user should auto updates to the database username who insert/modify the row

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the problem?

Comment: Your question and description don't match at all. Please mention what do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I re-typed my question. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL's `USER()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user) will yield the username provided when connecting to the data base.  You can include that in an INSERT or UPDATE statement. There's no way to do it completely automatically. You could use a trigger if you wanted it done without changing front-end code.